# Binding dynamic variables to datatable and processing each recursively

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm processing some rows from excel and querying them and storing in some variables(12 `var`s) as below. `dtremoverows` contains the data from excel.

```
 private System.Data.DataTable RemoveRows(System.Data.DataTable dtremoverows, bool mage)
 {
        System.Data.DataTable dtreturnrows = new System.Data.DataTable();
        int rowcount = dtremoverows.Rows.Count;
        var RemoveRows1 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString() == "" && r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "").ToList();
        var RemoveRows2 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString() == "" && r["QTY"].ToString() == "").ToList();
        var RemoveRows3 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:") || r["QTY"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:") || r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:") || r["WO_NO"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:") || r["ROLE_CODE"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:") || r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString().Contains("Total in Group:")).ToList();
        var RemoveRows4 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time") || r["QTY"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time") || r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time") || r["WO_NO"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time") || r["ROLE_CODE"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time") || r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString().Contains("Print Date/Time")).ToList();
        var RemoveRows5 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "" && r["QTY"].ToString() == "").ToList();
        var RemoveRows6 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString() == "0" || r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "0" || r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString() == "0").ToList();
        var RemoveRows7 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString().Contains("Total Amount") || r["QTY"].ToString().Contains("Total Resource Count")).ToList();
        var RemoveRows8 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["WO_NO"].ToString() == "" || r["QTY"].ToString() == "" || r["QTY"].ToString() == "0").ToList();
        var RemoveRows9 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "<None>" && (r["QTY"].ToString() == "" || r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString() == "")).ToList();
        var RemoveRows10 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["WO_NO"].ToString() == "Work Ord" && r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "Employee #/Sales Part #").ToList();
        var RemoveRows11 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["QTY"].ToString() == "0" || r["QTY"].ToString() == "").ToList();
        var RemoveRows12 = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["CRE_DATE"].ToString() == "" && r["WO_NO"].ToString() == "" && r["EMP_NO / Emp_Name"].ToString() == "" && r["ROLE_CODE"].ToString() == "" && r["CATALOG_NO"].ToString() == "" && r["QTY"].ToString() == "" && r["PLAN_LINE_NO"].ToString() == "" && r["WORK_ORDER_COST_TYPE"].ToString() == "" && r["WORK_ORDER_ACCOUNT_TYPE"].ToString() == "" && r["ORG_CODE"].ToString() == "" && r["CMNT"].ToString() == "").ToList();
 }
```

Then I am adding each of the variables as loop. Can I use this as a single recursive loop because I guess my coding(below) is deprecated.

```
 try
        {

            if (RemoveRows1.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in RemoveRows1)
                {
                    dtremoverows.Rows.Remove(row);

                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            if (RemoveRows2.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in RemoveRows2)
                {
                    dtremoverows.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

.........
And so on.. upto `RemoveRows12` and then merging as:

```
dtreturnrows.Merge(dtremoverows);
```

This works but I really need of better approach of coding this. If you have any suggestions please respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look into the snippet for the conditions `RemoveRows1`, `RemoveRows2` etc. for using much variables. Why not merge the conditions? I think you have to try something like this:

```
 var rowsToRemove = dtremoverows.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(r => 
                                (/* Condition for RemoveRows1 */) ||
                                (/* Condition for RemoveRows2 */) ||
                                (/* Condition for RemoveRows3 */) ||
                                (/* Condition for RemoveRows4 */) );
// And so on you can add conditions so that you will get a collection 
// of all rows that should be deleted from the table
// then iterate through those rows and perform delete like this:

foreach (var row in rowsToRemove)
{
     dtremoverows.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Please note : This is only a suggestion not an exact answer for the question, but it's more than a comment and that's why posting as an answer. Forgive me if it is against the rules.

Happy to help you.

Comment: Hello buddy, I am using many variables because I am extracting from various rows from excel and they need to be maintained. Thanks for your suggestion. If you have any other, I would love to hear it.

Comment: You can specify `various rows` in where condition since you are using `LINQ`.

Comment: I followed your snippet. Shows operator || cannot be used for lambda and bool operations

Comment: is it possible to show that code that you have tried? Hope that you may missed or misplaced brackets

Comment: Sorry being silly though. I resolved those errors. Will recheck the entire app and post you soon.

Answer (score 0):

the thumb role is that you shouldn't use recursions because it's not readable and not easy to understand and might cause a stack overflow exception if it gets to deep into the recursion loop.

when you can you should use simple loops to accomplish your iterations.